# Consider running the MergeSort algorithm on the following list: [9,5,7,3,2,1,6,8]

Tags: python, algorithm

```
def merge_sort(unsorted_list):
    '''(list of objects) -> list of objects Return a copy of unsorted_list
    sorted using the MergeSort algorithm
    '''
    #Base Case: an empty list is sorted, just return it
    if(unsorted_list == []):
        result = []
    #Base Case 2: a list with a single element is sorted, just return it
    #Question: How can we improve our base cases?
    elif(len(unsorted_list) == 1):
        result = unsorted_list
    else:
        midpoint = len(unsorted_list) //2
        #split the list into two smaller lists
        u1 = unsorted_list[:midpoint]
        u2 = unsorted_list[midpoint:]
        #recursively sort each list
        s1 = merge_sort(u1)
        s2 = merge_sort(u2)
        #merge the two sorted lists
        sorted_list = merge(s1,s2)
        result = sorted_list
    return result

def merge(s1, s2):
    '''(list of objects, list of objects) -> list of objets
    Merge sorted lists s1 and s2 into a single sorted list     and return it
    '''
    #index1 and index2 will hold our current place in s1     and s2 respectively
    i1 = 0
    i2 = 0
    #loop through s1 and s2 comparing the current indicies, and moving
    #the greater element into the sorted list
    sorted_list = []
    while(i1 < len(s1) and i2 < len(s2)):
        if(s1[i1] < s2[i2]):
            sorted_list.append(s1[i1])
            i1 +=1
        else:
            sorted_list.append(s2[i2])
            i2 +=1
    #append the rest of whichever list has not been finished to the end of
    #the sorted list
    if(i1 < len(s1)):
        sorted_list += s1[i1:]
    else:
        sorted_list += s2[i2:]
    return sorted_list
```

QUESTION:

Consider running the MergeSort algorithm on the following list:

[9,5,7,3,2,1,6,8]

What sub-lists will merge be called on over the course of the sort?
For example, if merge will be called twice, once to merge the lists [a,b,c] and [d,e,f], and once to
merge the lists [x,y,z] and [w], your answer would be:

merge([a,b,c],[d,e,f])

merge([x,y,z],[w])

---

I don't get it. I get the merge sort algorithm, I just don't know what its asking.

Wouldn't my answer be merge([3,5,7,9], [1,2,6,8]) ?

[9,5,7,3,2,1,6,8]

[9,5,7,3] [2,1,6,8]

[9, 5] [7, 3]

[9] [5]

Or would be merge([9], [5])

merge([7], [3])

If we go in order?

Answer (score 0):

```
python -i merge.py
>>> merge_sort([9,5,7,3,2,1,6,8])
[9] [5]
[7] [3]
[5, 9] [3, 7]
[2] [1]
[6] [8]
[1, 2] [6, 8]
[3, 5, 7, 9] [1, 2, 6, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

This is the bottom-up approach of Merge sort. To break down the list into n sublists and iteratively merge sublists back and forth between two buffers [Wiki definition]

In this case. Recursion will happen until there is only the first two elements left and then they are trivially sorted. Then the next two elements are trivially sorted (check Base Case #2 ). Then 5,9 and 3,7 are merged to form `[3,5,7,9]` and this same set of procedures happens on the second half of the list as well. `[2,1,6,8]` and as a final step both these sorted lists are merged to form the final sorted list!